# Kotlin- How to access an Object/Shared Instance inside an XML file

Tags: xml, kotlin

I'm an iOS developer currently learning Android development using Kotlin. I have an object/shared instance(iOS term):

```
object AppAppearance {
    val cornerRadius = "10dp"
}
```

[image]

How can I access the above inside an XML file?

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners android:radius="${AppAppearance.cornerRadius}"/> // <---- This doesn't work
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

</shape>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have constants you want to use in XML, you should define them in XML, not in Kotlin. For example, in `res/values/` create a file named `appearance.xml` and put:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="cornerRadius">10dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

You can put other line items in this file in the `resources` block.

And in your file that uses it:

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners android:radius="@dimen/cornerRadius"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

</shape>
```

It is possible to read values from Kotlin using [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding), but that's not for constants. It reads member properties or functions of the activity/fragment that the view is attached to.

If all this seems convoluted and messy, that's because it is. The [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/courses/jetpack-compose/course) UI system is their new way of creating UI directly in Kotlin code so you aren't having to jump back and forth between languages. But its also a completely different model of how to do UI (the UI is built from the data model with logic instead of you imperatively hooking up a UI to the data), so it's not a direct replacement. You might find that you prefer it though.

Comment: "If all this seems convoluted and messy, that's because it is", lol. This definitely is messy. iOS/Swift is so much easier. All we have to do is create the shared instance class as in: `class AppAppearance { static let shared = AppAppearance(); let cornerRadius = "10dp" }` and then we can use it anywhere inside the entire app. I guess coming from an iOS background this all seems very foreign to me. I notice a lot of things in Android Studio are both **difficult** and **extremely easy** compared to Xcode. Thanks for the explantation!